# How to use two dataset in the same code in one shot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have a pre-specified model that runs smoothly. The problem is that I have two datasets for the same model. The two datasets change just on the basis of the rows:e.g. dataset 1 goes from 1 to 60 and dataset 2 from 61 to 115. All the variables are the same. I would like to avoid computing the same code twice. I'd rather write it nicely and compute it in one shot.

I will give you an example dataset with my model:

```
data = rand(115,5)

Y_data = data(1:60, :) % dataset 1
Y_data = data(61:115, :) % dataset 2

% This is the model that runs nicely on dataset Y_data. I wanted to avoid to run the model twice,
% first with Y_data from row 1 to 60 and then from row to 61 to 100. I would like to do it in one shot
% the code for the model is fully automated so it's just a matter of making it work first on dataset 1 and then
% on dataset 2 in one unique code
T = size(Y_data,1);
P  = 3; % number of lags used in LP for controls
H_min = 1; 
H_max = 25; 
y  = Y_data(:,1); % endogenous variable
x  = Y_data(:,2); % shock 
w  = lagmatrix(Y_data(:,[3:5]), 1:P ); 
newData = cat(2, y, x, w)
% Remove missings from data
newData(any(isnan(newData), 2), :) = [];
% Re-declare variables after removing missings
y  = newData(:,1); % endogenous variable
x  = newData(:,2); % shock
w = newData(:,3:size(newData,2)); % control variables and lags
r = 3; 
lambda = 10000; 
slp    = locproj(y,x,w,H_min,H_max,'smooth',r,lambda); 
%% Cross-Validation Choice of Lambda
slp = locproj(y,x,w,H_min,H_max,'smooth',r,0.01);
lambda = [1:10:1000] * T;
slp    = locproj_cv(slp,5,lambda);
lambda_opt = lambda( min( slp.rss ) == slp.rss );
%% Confidence Intervals
r      = 3;
slp    = locproj(y,x,w,H_min,H_max,'smooth',r,lambda_opt); 
slp    = locproj_conf(slp,H_max,lambda_opt/2);
```

What I thought it could sort this out was using if/else, something like:

```
% This is wrong but it gives you an idea of what I was trying to do and get
% trying to tell MATLAB, fun the code first from dataset 1 (row 1:60) and then the same on dataset 2 (from row 61:115)

k = 1:60

if  k == 1

Y_data = Y_data;
    
else

       Y_data = data(61:115, :);
end

% model code as above just here - not to make it too long
% the output therefore should save both results for dataset1 and dataset2
```

I got stuck and don't manage to go ahead. Can anyone help me? It would make my day.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to achieve this. Here are two simple ones.

Make a function `dataAnalysis(Y_data)` and simply do

```
[slp,lambdaOpt] = dataAnalysis(data(1:60,:))
[slp2,lambdaOpt2] = dataAnalysis(data(61:115,:))
```

You function could look like

```
function [slp,lambdaOpt] = dataAnalysis(data)
% This is the model that runs nicely on dataset Y_data. I wanted to avoid to run the model twice,
% first with Y_data from row 1 to 60 and then from row to 61 to 100. I would like to do it in one shot
% the code for the model is fully automated so it's just a matter of making it work first on dataset 1 and then
% on dataset 2 in one unique code
T = size(Y_data,1);
P  = 3; % number of lags used in LP for controls
H_min = 1; 
H_max = 25; 
% etc. etc...
% Add in whatever output variables are important
```

Alternatively, use a loop like you tried:

```
indices = {1:60, 61:115};
for k = 1:2
    Y_Data = data(indices{k},:);

    % your model code operating on Y_data
    % store any results here as either variable(k) (scalar data)
    % or variable {k} (non-scalar data)
end
```